# The driveways between the adjacent buildings

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

There are three buildings along the same stretch of road next to one another. Lets call them ***Building A, Building B and Building C***. Both the hearer and I are talking about ***Building B***.

- ***Building B*** is in the middle.
- There is a *driveway* between ***Building A and Building B***
- There is a *driveway* between ***Building B and Building C***

I would like to tell them about the driveways.

If I say

> the driveways between the adjacent buildings

Does that make sense?

And if I were to say there are two driveways, should I say

> There are driveways on either side of ***Building B***

or

> There are driveways on both sides of ***Building B***

Comment: Understanding "the driveways between the adjacent buildings" would depend on the context and how well the reader understands the layout, as well as how precise you need to be. A house could have multiple driveways; a driveway could serve one or more houses; the houses could be in a straight line or offset from each other. "Three houses separated by driveways" is fairly clear but doesn't explain everything (which driveway belongs to which house?). Adding a diagram would be useful (both to this question and your actual text.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't mean *alleys*?

> **[Alley](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/alley):** a passage, as through a continuous row of houses, permitting access
> from the street to backyards, garages, etc.

vs.

> **[Driveway](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/driveway):** a road, especially a private one, leading from a street or other
> thoroughfare to a building, house, garage, etc.

To me, a driveway would connect to a specific building/location, whereas the concept of a passage/road between several buildings in a row more describes an alley.  (Maybe this is a US English specific preference.)

To answer your questions:

> The driveways/alleys between the adjacent buildings

The above makes sense.

> There is a/an driveway/alley on either side of Building B
>
> There is a/an driveway/alley on both sides of Building B

For both, I would make it singular, as you are talking about one on each side. I am being a pedant, but the reason is the plural form could indicate multiple driveways/alleys on either side.

Comment: thanks. I'm referring to driveway as is a small private road. To clarify, by saying ***the driveways between the adjacent buildings*** the hearer will understand as there is a driveway on each side of Building B? There is a driveway *between A and B*, and a *driveway between B and C*?

Comment: [Here's a shared driveway in the UK](http://woodside-park.com/shared-driveways/). There may be regional differences in meaning.